# Do you think every one in planetary colony would be in mechs

Tags: space-colonization, colonies

Do think that in a planetary colony every one would be in mechs. when there not in side the base or do you think that they just be in suits to protect them from the atmosphere.

Comment: Depends on a colony and planetary environment.

Comment: This relies entirely on the environment of the planet in question. This needs a lot more detail regarding the world its set in, and it could also benefit from being worded in such a way that isnt entirely opinion based (check out the site [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) for more details)

Comment: @Psycrow To write a link you have to write `[tour](link/to/tour)`, but in the comments you can also use magic links such as `[tour]` and `[help]` or `[edit]`

Comment: One thing to consider, mech are *very* expensive and require maintenance.  If the only individuals who go outside are in mechs, that will severely limit how many individuals go outside, and what they will do.  There won't be any sight-seeing, that's for sure

Comment: I fixed the link, managed to mistype a { instead of a (, however I wasn't aware of the magic shortcuts so thanks for that! Saves me from googling for the tour in future

Comment: This questions is more or less the definition of opinion-based. Questions on this site are supposed to be narrowly asked in such a way that there is a 'right' answer. Your question starts with 'Do you think,' which is a red flag right off the top. Consider re-asking it in the form "On a planetary colony with conditions X and Y, would people be able to go outside without mech suits?". For now, I'm voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: if suits work and are cheaper than mechs, the people that don't need to be in mechs would be in suits.

Comment: I voted to close this as **too broad** because it's impossible to answer without knowing anything about the planet in question.

Comment: This qustion has already received a vote to reopen.  I doubt that will happen unless a great deal of detail is provided about the planet, the "mechs," and the circumstances of the colony.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the environment, and resources of the colonies. Do they need mecs to survive outside, or will simple space suit be enough? For example, the if your colonizing mars you probably only need a suit. But you need a high science fiction level mec if you ever wanted to walk on the surface of Venus. If they do need mec to living on the surface, do they have the resources to give everyone mecs or can only a handful of people afford one?